# void function in C++ not read

Tags: c++

Im struggled with a void function in C++. The void function is supposed to take two arrays as arguments, making some operations over them and returning them both modified. However, when called in the program, the array I set as an input hasnt changed.

The function uses the Jacobi eigenvalue algorithm, so the initial matrices D and VV should be returned in the diagonal basis, being "dim" the dimension.

jacobi (dim,VV,D);

When writing that line in the main function, both D and VV haven't changed. Both D and VV are defined as dynamical arrays (pointers to pointers), does that have any effect at all? Shouldnt the command above return the new D and VV ? When making a "cout" inside the void function, both D and VV seem to be changed under operations, but not when called from the main function! Thanks!

Comment: You really need to show your code instead of trying to describe it

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: Show your code. You probably should return a value, or pass arguments by reference. Use genuine C++ style: smart pointers, containers, etc.

Comment: Provide a [MCVE] that reproduces the problem please.

Comment: Even if this is your first question, you have been a member for over three years, which means you should have had plenty of time to have [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learned how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

You're obviously assigning the parameters to something else in the function.

Pass the function parameters *by reference* instead.

i.e. change the function `jacobi(A dim, B VV, C D)` where A, B, and C are your current specific types to

`jacobi(A& dim, B& VV, C& D)`

The `&` denotes a reference.

Comment: Sorry about it guys, but finally I could solve it by just creting pointers inside the function and returning them! Thanks anyway for the answers